# Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Some images just fail to upload with mentioned error message. For example: What is wrong with this image that it is refused?

http://media.digikey.com/Photos/FCI%20Photos/10118192-0001LF.JPG

[image]

This happens every once in a while with an image.

**My solution:** Just copy/paste it in the GIMP, save it and it uploads fine.

---

**EDIT1:** Confirmed that [@PeterJ's solutions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/failed-to-upload-image-the-format-is-not-supported?noredirect=1#comment6362_2913) works too.

Comment: I get that a lot as well, in fact for me it often works just by saving the image to my local disk without any editing.

Comment: Does it happen when uploading via the URL?

Comment: @clabacchio updated

Comment: I also had some problems when updating from web, but I don't know exactly the reason. Have you tried on meta.so?

Comment: @clabacchio [obviously not](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2914/8627)

Comment: I have the same issue with https://image.frl/i/4cglt4c57oodkl35.png which is a valid APNG image. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

From [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130633/error-messages-when-uploading-an-image-from-the-web):

> After trying and failing a couple of times (and even trying different images), it finally occurred to me that the image was fine, but the original host blocked imgur from accessing it.

And in the answer:

> Unfortunately, when it comes to passing a URL to imgur, we can only display what they tell us (which ends up being a 400 error).

So the problem is not about the file type, but about the source site blocking imgur from accessing the image and giving a 400 error.

Comment: Three or four times I've had the same problem with an image already on imgur, for example I tried the following a few times to make sure it wasn't a temporary problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJcUf.jpg (that's a "schematic" a new user just posted).